# How to send a request from servlets to another server

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to send a request to another server from my servlet and get the response being in the same servlet. For Example: arequest :

```
http://www.anotherserver.com?para=pValue
```

is sent to anotherserver, and get the response which it sends and then process the response.

Comment: Did you take a look to the RequestDispacther?

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the response which the other server send in RequestDispatcher ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache HttpClient (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) in your Java code to make HTTP calls.

Example: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java

Comment: thanks. but how can I find a direct answer. Would u be more specific please?